# How to get length of returned from filter array?

Tags: angularjs

I have custom filter in ng-repeat.
I need to find out length of returned array.How to do it?
here is html:

```
 <div  ng-repeat="item in vm.work_items | itemsInFolder: search">
      <div>item.name</div>
 </div>
 <div>{{returnedArray.length}}</div> //I need set returned value here.
```

filter:

```
 .filter('itemsInFolder', function($window, NamesService) {
        return function (items, input) {
            if(!input) {
                return items;
            } else {
            var out = [];
            items.forEach(function(item){
             //here goes some custom logic, which returns array;
             out.push(item);
               }
          return out;
        }
  });
```

Comment: yes, go through the above link, you will get the answer.

Comment: super it works! thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

**New feature as in Angular 1.3**, you can extend the `ng-repeat` directive with the `as` option.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.work_items | itemsInFolder: search as results">
    <div>item.name</div>
</div>

<p>{{results.length}}</p>
```

Comment: thanks .I've tried like adviced in comments.